# ID: Serated-leafed seedling

Tags: species-identification, botany

A seedling has popped up in one of my planters (acid soil; Toronto, Ontario).

What is it?

---

June 4, 2020:

[image]

---

June 20, 2020:

[image]

[image]

Comment: it's a kind of tree, perhaps a kind of oak. https://ask.extension.org/questions/332861

Comment: @com.prehensible The leaves look opposite. Are there Oaks with opposite leaves?

Comment: Yes i wasn't that convinced either that it's an oak, it just has a lot in common and also some differences. You could tell straight away from it's woodyness and toughness if its a tree by feeling it, if its twiggy its a tree, time will tell.

Answer (score 2):

An extension of com.prehensible's comment -- your sapling could be a [bur oak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quercus_macrocarpa).  It is older than the seedling pictured below, but retains a similar [cotyledon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cotyledon).  The range of this species [includes Ontario](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quercus_macrocarpa#/media/File:Quercus_macrocarpa_range_map_1.png).

> [image: seedling bur oak]
>
> **bur oak seedling**
> Photo by Todd Dwyer, via [Flickr](https://www.flickr.com/photos/ret0dd/4206072061)
> (please ignore the image artifact -- an effect of resizing)

Your photo appears to show the tree at a stage after the seedling shown above and before the more mature sapling shown here:

> [image: sapling bur oak]
>
> **bur oak sapling**
> Photo by John T. Fowler, [Alamy Stock Photo](https://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-bur-oak-seedling-quercus-macrocarpa-10833460.html)

Comment: Thanks! For what it's worth, an aquaintance had this comment: "...I don't think it's an oak of any species, since it has normal cotyledon (seed) leaves above ground. Oak cotyledons are modified to store food for the seedling, so they don't resemble leaves and usually don't emerge from the acorn. I don't think the example photo posted to Stack Exchange is an oak either." ... Food for thought?

Comment: [Seedling emergence patterns - PDF](https://www.uky.edu/hort/sites/www.uky.edu.hort/files/pages-attachments/Seedling%20emergence%20patterns.pdf): *"...the cotyledons remain underground and the stem (epicotyl)
emerges above ground. This pattern is called hypogeous. Large seeded plants like
Kentucky coffeetree and **oaks** tend to have hypogeous germination."*

Comment: *..."the first photo is not an oak. The second one (the older plant) is an oak, but the bristles on the leaf lobes mean it's not a bur oak."*

Comment: A diagram from [The Woody-plant Seed Manual - United States Forest Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSALI.png) -- Google Books link [here](https://books.google.ca/books?id=uPNJAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA302&lpg=PA302&dq=%22Quercus+macrocarpa%22+%22hypogeous%22&source=bl&ots=iREKvaCA2Q&sig=ACfU3U31--d8_3O5NlNYqdqF8RB981-zSg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiPqeXvsevpAhVIWs0KHWkOAJcQ6AEwAXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Quercus%20macrocarpa%22%20%22hypogeous%22&f=false).

Comment: @Wilson it sounds like your acquaintance is quite knowledgable! I don’t suppose you can convince her/him to make an account on biology.SE? ;)

Answer (score 1):

With regard to the seedling being an oak, just gently excavate around the stem - the acorn will still be there to identify. You can do this without hurting the roots.

Answer (score 1):

The hairy stem and leaf pattern remind me of elms. Wikipedia has an example of american elm seedlings which look quite similar to what you have to me:

[image: Seedlings of Ulmus americana]